# Удаление всей мета-информации из .NET-бинарника

Tags: c#, .net

Есть ли способ почистить .NET сборку, чтобы в ней не осталось никакой посторонней информации?

Настройки, предлагаемые самой VS недостаточны - многое остается видимым и в релизной версии сборки. PE-Упаковщики - хороший вариант, но интересно, можно ли обойтись без них?

В совершенстве, по выходному бинарному(исполняемому) файлу нельзя бы было даже распознать язык, на котором он был написан. Есть ли какие-нибудь тулзы для этого?

Comment: .NET-сборка должна в любом случае содержать .NET-метаданные, так что там будут и имена классов, и всё такое.

Comment: Если вы хотите сделать так, что бы сборку нельзя было изучить, то смотрите в сторону обфускаторов.